# Getting a modal to pop up when validation is false

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm trying to create a page that when you click on add product button a modal pops up with a form that gets filled out.
What I'm trying to do is after you've submitted the form and there are errors then I would like for it to redirect back
and have the modal popup with the error messages.

Here is my code

My controller

```
public function  addProduct(Product $product)
{
    $validator = Validator::make(request()->all(), [
        'title' => 'required'
    ]);

    if($validator->fails())
    {
        return redirect()->back()->with([
            'errors' => $validator->errors()
        ])
    }
}
```

My blade file

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addProductModal">
    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add Product
</button>

@include('admin.product.add-product')
```

and this is my modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="addProductModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="addProductModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="addProductModalLabel">Add a Product</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>

            <form action="{{ route('admin.product.addProduct') }}" method="post">
                @csrf

                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name">Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>
    
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can use https://github.com/realrashid/sweet-alert

Comment: You can submit your form using ajax instead of simple form submit. if validation fail then return response with errors that you have to set for respective fields in model popup else response as sucess at time close model popup and refresh Page using jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that using sessions.

I'm using `Form Requests` for validation, and in my `CreateCategoryRequest` I added:

```
public function withValidator($validator)
{
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        \Session::flash('create_category_error', 'Create category validation failed!');
    }

}
```

In blade:

```
@if (session('create_category_error'))      
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
</script>
@endif
```

Yes it's that simple :P

Happy coding!

Comment: lol. I can't believe it was that simple. Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

You can use this also.

```
<!-- Test if validation failed; hence show modal -->

@if($errors->getBag('default')->first('name') != '')
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#addProductModal").modal('show');
    });
</script>
@endif
```